# coffee with cardamom

Tags: health, ground-coffee, milk

I recently tried coffee with some cardamom spice which tasted really great. I'm still wondering if it has any negative impact on health if you drink a lot of cups of coffee with cardamom during the day. I usually add some spoons of brown sugar and sometimes even skimmed milk, in the end I add small spoon of ground cardamom and stirr it up. I use regular ground coffee from the supermarket and consume probably around 3-5 cups per day, should I consume less? Are there any food/drinks I should avoid after drinking coffee with cardamom?

Comment: Isn't sugar is the one to avoid? I see no harm in cardamom, but I'm not a doctor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebMD does list some negative side-effects when [taking cardamom](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-614/cardamom).  Looks like cardamom has health benefits too.

But I have a suggestion (gleaned from the back of my jar of cardamom pods). Instead of using a spoonful of ground cardamom, consider getting cardamom pods, squeezing 2 or 3 of them to crack them a little bit and placing those in your coffee cup.  It definitely augments the taste of the coffee in the positive direction, plus you're not eating ground cardamom.

Answer (score 1):

Cardamon is a great addition to coffee. It is maybe more suitable for winter, since it makes you feel warm.